# Alloc init retain?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

Can anybody explain why the retain count of this line of code:

```
[[[SomeClass alloc] init] retain]
```

Is two? I'm only calling retain once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because alloc adds 1 to the retain count. You should read Apple's [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html).

Answer (score 6):

The retain count is two because `[alloc]` also increases the retain count. Strictly speaking the retain count of an object isn't just how many times you've called retain, but how many things are holding on to it.

Answer (score 4):

If you create an object, using a method who's name begins with `alloc, new, copy or mutableCopy`, or you `retain` an object, its retain count is increased by 1

If you `release` or `autorelease` an object, it's retain count decreases by 1

In your example code, both `alloc` and `retain` increase the retain count by 1.

See Apple's docs for further details:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html